# Правильно ли оформлено предложение?

Tags: пунктуация

Все: и товарищи,и дамы - стали уверять Беликова, что он должен жениться.
Как объяснить постановку тире?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если обобщающее слово (в вашем случае - ВСЕ) стоит перед однородными членами предложения, но предложение этим не заканчивается, то перед однородными членами ставится двоеточие, а после них перед остальной часть предложения - тире. Сравните: "*Все: и этот голубой разлив реки, и это небо, и дали, и пароход - казалось огромным, необъятным, воздушным, полным напряженного движения.*" (Ф.Гладков).

Answer (score 0):

Если ряд однородных членов, стоящих после обобщающего слова,  не завершает предложение, то после него перед продолжением предложения ставится тире. Здесь обобщающее слово ВСЕ, после него двоеточие перед однородными членами, а после них - тире.